# Laravel 5 Same value for each input

Tags: input, laravel-5

Hello and here is my problem.

I have a hidden field on my form for registering candidates that supplies a `purchase_order_number` to a candidate; this is generated using `$purchase_order_number = Str::quickRandom(7);` in the create view.
I will hopefully use this to group candidates later on.

As more than one candidate can be registered at once, I would like the value of this hidden field to be input for each candidate. I have tried several things but with no success.

Here is the controller for my create view:

```
public function centreQualification($id)
{
    $centre = Centre::with('sites')->find($id);
    $purchase_order_number = Str::quickRandom(7);
    return view('vault.create', compact('centre','purchase_order_number'));
}
```

And here is the view itself:

```
@extends('app')
@section('content')
    <h1>Register New Candidates</h1>
    <hr/>
    {!! Form::open(['url' => 'candidates', 'name' =>  'candidate_registration_form', 'id' =>  'candidate_registration_form'] ) !!}
    {!! Form::label('qualification_id','Qualification:') !!}
    <select name="qualification_id" class="form-control">
        @foreach($centre->qualification as $qualification)
            <option value="{{ $qualification->id  }}">{{ $qualification->title }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>

    <input type="text" name="purchase_order_number" id="purchase_order_number" value="{{ $purchase_order_number }}" />

    <hr/>
    @include ('errors.list')
    @include ('vault.form')

    {!! Form::close() !!}
@stop
```

Now when I store (create) a new candidate I have this controller function:

```
public function store(CandidateRequest $request)
{
    $candidateInput = Input::get('candidates');
    foreach ($candidateInput as $candidate)
    {
        $candidate = Candidate::create($candidate);
    }

    return redirect('candidates');
}
```

Is there any way to attach this `$purchase_order_number` to each candidate?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="hidden" 
    name="purchase_order_number" 
    id="purchase_order_number" 
    value="{{ $purchase_order_number }}" />
```

This creates a hidden field with the `purchase_order_number`.
In your `store()` method, get it using

```
$request->input('purchase_order_number');
```

Comment: Thank for the help but that didn’t work for me. It wasn’t passing the number to the table. 
I have tried to array_merge the two sets of values but it retuns array:6     [▼
  "candidate_number" => "5645"
  "givennames" => "fgfgf"
  "familyname" => "dfgfg"
  "dob" => "01/01/2015"
  "uln" => "45565445"
  0 => "5874569"

Comment: What exactly is the ouput of `Str::quickRandom(7);`?